# Есть ли возможность убрать ненужную информацию в консоли разработчика во вкладке network?

Tags: отладка, google-chrome-devtools

Есть ли возможность убрать в консоли разработчика во вкладке `network` ненужную информацию?

Меня уже бесит постоянно искать нужный мне запрос среди большого количества мусора. Есть ли способ убрать весь ненужный хлам?

Работаю из google chrome

[image: Пример ненужной информации]

Comment: А панельки выше (Preserve log, Disanle cache, ... Filter, Invert, ... All, Ferch, XHR, ...) не помогают?  ))

Comment: @Zombotron, я делал xhr, но у меня запросы все равно идут только xhr, так-что это не помогает :(

Comment: Поэтому и спрашиваю есть ли какие-либо способы возможно отфильтровать по нейминг, возможно, или что-то в это роде

Comment: Поле Filter перед Invert, не?

Comment: @Zombotron, filter перед invert? Можешь подсказать что это?

Comment: А, все кажись понял о чем ты. В принципе как вариант. Спасибо)